# Unable to set tr background-color with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to change the background color of a table row with jquery.
It works with font color but for some reason not with the background color.

this works:
`$(this).parent('tr').css('color', 'red');`

but this does not:
`$(this).parent('tr').css('background-color', 'green');`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
I couldn't find a similar case on the internet.

```js
$(document).on('click', "td", function(event) {
  $(this).parent('tr').css('color', 'red');
  $(this).parent('tr').css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

th {
  background-color: #dce0e3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have given td background color `#f5f5f5` that's why it's not happening. In jquery you are applying it to tr.

```js
$(document).on('click', "td", function(event) {
  $(this).parent('tr').css('color', 'red');
  $(this).parent('tr').css('background-color', 'green');
  $(this).parent('tr').find('td').css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

th {
  background-color: #dce0e3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks priya_singh, that worked. I will accept it as an answer when possible

Comment: This approach will require more work in a case if background color will need to be removed

Comment: I use the following for that:  $(table).find("td,tr").removeAttr('style');

Comment: @Flying . you are right. But if he want backgound-color #f5f5f5. he have to give it to tr instead of td in css.

Comment: @Dummy Yes, you can do. Its a alternate solution.

Comment: @priya_singh if course, you're right. Actually much better way is to use CSS classes instead of trying to applying CSS styles directly. It is simpler and more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct, but you can't see background code assigned to `tr` because you have `td {background-color: #f5f5f5;}` style that paints over your `tr`.